# PHP, JAVA прослушка (постоянная работа скрипта)

Tags: cron, php, java

Добрый день!
Каким образом можно реализовать постоянную работу скрипта, который бегает по базе и просматривает её изменения?

Пример:

- Клиент1: в режиме ожидания
- Клиент2: действие, запись в БД флага действия
- Сервер: чтение БД, передача флага действия из БД  Клиенту2
- Клиент1: реакция на флаг дейсвтия

Мои мысли:

1. Запускать скрипт по cron
2. Организовать скрипт цикл и запускать по cron
3. Javascript setInterval + ajax

Вероятные проблемы:

1. Прослушка нужна постоянная и не ясно, с какой периодичностью запускать скрипт по cron с учётом того, что база по размеру приличная и невозможно просчитать динамически время выполнения скрипта.
2. Нагрузка на сервер. Скорее всего, нужно арендовать выделенный сервер.
3. Такая же проблема как и в первом случае, неизвестен интервал времени запуска скрипта, хотя предполагаю, что по окончании работы скрипта происходит его перезапуск (опять нагрузка на сервер).

Что посоветуете Вы? Спасибо.

Comment: а почему не упомянули какая у вас БД ? в Oracle, например, есть встроенная система очередей

Comment: База MYSQL. Видимо я поторопился.

Answer (score 3):

Раз речь идет о cron, то будем считать, что сервер на *nix.

Можно написать скрипт (из под cron), который определяет, не работает ли он уже и если предыдущий запуск еще  не закончил работу, то новый просто делает exit.

Проверять проще всего как-то так.

```
#!/bin/sh

PIDFILE="xaxa.pid"

if [ -f ${PIDFILE} ]; then
    pid=`cat ${PIDFILE}` 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    ps -ef | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep ${pid} >/dev/null && exit
fi

echo  $$ >xaxa.pid
echo Working...
....
```

Такой скрипт можно запускать хоть раз в секунду, сервер не перегрузится работой.

Кстати, что у Вас за клиенты, из под браузера или локальные скрипты (программы) ?

Comment: Клиент браузер.
Спасибо за идею!

Answer (score 2):

Тут надо копать в сторону **Comet** и **Message Queueing**. Т.е. - передавать сообщение от Клиента2 к Клиенту1 еще ДО помещения в базу. Не знаю, что за серверный язык используете, но если даже и PHP, то и на нем есть реализации Comet-решений (вроде phpDaemon зовется).

По **Comet** рекомендую [эту статью](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet/server-patterns)

По **MQ** рекомендую почитать про ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, [AMQP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMQP), [Mongrel2](http://pyobject.ru/blog/2010/11/01/mongrel2/)

А вообще - это постоянный спор: частый аякс-запрос или помучиться с кометом.

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая, что упоминается php, значит с большой вероятностью база - mysql. В это случае есть интересное решение. Вот здесь http://www.michurin.com.ru/mysql-log.shtml описано как включить логирование. Теперь, пишете на любимом языке программу, которая по крону будет запускаться каждый час/сутки/минуту, который будет проверять текущий размер лога и вычитывать разницу. А потом ее анализировать.

Comment: Спасибо за идею.
Сама реализация выглядит проще на мой взгляд. При INSERT в базу клиентом2 создавать файл на сервере с номером запроса (обычный инкремент) и далее скриптом анализировать. По идее нет смысла включать mysql log.
Или я чего-то не понял?

Проблема ещё в том, что "прослушка" должна запускаться каждые 5 секунд, грубо говоря она должна работать всегда.

Comment: кроме insert'ов, есть ещё много других запросов. Но если только вставки, то никаких проблем. Автоинткремент легко отслеживать. А вот с какой частотой запускать - это вам лучше знать.